# Replace phrase in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to replace a particular string in given format. Please see the highlighted phrase for getting the difference.

'67,Yoga Pura,**"15440 N. 7th Street, Suite 1"**,Phoenix,AZ,85022,-112.066286,33.627028,26'

Into

'67,Yoga Pura,**15440 N. 7th Street Suite 1**,Phoenix,AZ,85022,-112.066286,33.627028,26'

I'm trying to remove comma in phrase which is enclosed by double qoutes. I know how to replace it but I dont know how to set this phrase **"15440 N. 7th Street, Suite 1"** in a variable.

```
$lines = preg_replace('/"[^"]+"/', 'new formatted text', $lines);
```

Please help

Comment: So in other words you have a CSV row and you want to make each column comma-free (and unwrapped by quotes)?

Comment: yes you are 100% right

Comment: Your sample input and output don't match the description. Do you want to remove the double quotes, or the commas, or both?

Comment: Then you should be using the right tool for the job: a CSV parser, not a regex.

Comment: actually I first want to check if the string has double qoutes then remove both double qoutes and commas.

Comment: @TimPietzcker how can i parse a single string in csv format properly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do it with regex:

```
$str = '67,Yoga Pura,"15440 N. 7th Street, Suite ",Phoenix,AZ,85022,-112.066286,33.627028,26';
echo preg_replace ( '#"(.*?),(.*?)"#', '$1$2', $str );
```

Output:

```
67,Yoga Pura,15440 N. 7th Street Suite 1,Phoenix,AZ,85022,-112.066286,33.627028,26
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match all the segments between double quotes, and then use a callback function to strip the double quotes/commas from them:

```
$string = '67,Yoga Pura,"15440 N. 7th Street, Suite 1",Phoenix,AZ,85022,-112.066286,33.627028,26';

function strip_commas($str) {
  return str_replace(array(',', '"'), '', $str[0]);
}

$string = preg_replace_callback('/".*?"/', "strip_commas", $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$text = preg_replace('/^(.*)"([^"]*),([^"]*)"(.*)$/', '${2}${3}', $text);
```

to isolate the part between `"` and remove your `,`

or this :

```
$text = preg_replace('/"([^"]*),([^"]*)"/', '${1}${2}', $text);
```

Just to remove the `,` between `"`.

It seems to work well

[working example here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0b23295e1df0d5c7b8c80395ce840066e1f73775)

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookahead

```
/,(?=(([^"]*"[^"]*"[^"]*[^"]*"[^"]*)+|[^"]*"[^"]*)$)/
       ----------------------------  _ ----------
                   |                 |       |->matches a single odd " till end
                   |                 |->OR
                   |-> matches 1 to many occurrences of 3 " till end
```

So this would match `,` only if it has **odd number** of `"` followed by it

---

Obviously this won't work  for nested `"`

Answer (score 0):

There's probably some shorthand callback slice 'n merge one-line-wonder for this, but let's do it straight:

```
$row = '67,Yoga Pura,"15440 N. 7th Street, Suite 1",Phoenix,AZ,85022,-112.066286,33.627028,26';
$parsed = str_getcsv($row);
$parsed2 = array();
$i = 0;

while ($col = array_shift($parsed)) {
    array_push($parsed2, str_replace(',', '', $col));
}
```

https://ignite.io/code/51496970ec221ee821000003

Of course that's using [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php), the simplest way to parse a CSV row from a string (if you have PHP >= 5.3.0).

Slightly shorter:

```
$row = '67,Yoga Pura,"15440 N. 7th Street, Suite 1",Phoenix,AZ,85022,-112.066286,33.627028,26';
$parsed = str_replace(',', '', str_getcsv($row));

print_r($parsed);

echo implode(',', $parsed);
```

https://ignite.io/code/51496b2bec221ee821000004